# Exclude matched regex pattern

Tags: regex

I want to match all consecutive lines, prefixed with a space until a line starts without a space!

The problem is that the "end pattern" [^ ] is part of the match. The end pattern is a start-of-line not starting with a space.

The used pattern: `(?im)(?:^( (?s:.*?))(?:^[^ ]))  /g`

See example at
https://regex101.com/r/msVC5b/1

Please can anyone help me? I've spent hours and hours searching on SO and trying negative lookarounds ;)

Comment: By "all lines preceeding with a space" do you mean `\n\s+` or `\s+\n` ?

Comment: `/\A(.*?)(?=^(?! ))/sm`

Comment: `/\A((?: [^\n]*\n)*)/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've interpreted your request right, you're overthinking it. The pattern you want is this:

```
/(?:^ .+\n)+/gm
```

What it'll do is match every line that starts with a space and ends with a newline, one or more times, in a contiguous fashion.

[Demo on Regex101 (adapted from yours)](https://regex101.com/r/msVC5b/6)